Determinants of long term interest rates
Can you pls explain why long-term nominal interest rates should be around of the level of nominal potential GDP? What would be the macroeconomic forces behind it?

For the future, it might help to share what course you are taking and what reading is recommended. This way we'll know how best to answer your question, what notation to use etc.

I think the logic can look somewhat like this.
Decomposition of nominal GDP growth
Following Olivier Blanchard's coursebook (page 51):

The rate of growth of nominal GDP is equal to the rate of inflation
plus the rate of growth of real GDP.

Thus,
$$
g_{\text{nominal}} = \pi + g_{\text{real}} \tag{*}\label{eq1}.
$$
Fisher equation
The Fisher equation relates nominal interest rates $i$ to real interest rates $r$ and expected inflation $\pi^e$:
$$
i = r + \pi^e.
$$
In the long run, expected inflation aligns with actual inflation, so:
$$
i \approx r + \pi.
$$
Real interest rates and real GDP growth
Over the long run, real interest rates $r$ tend to align with the growth rate of real GDP $g_{\text{real}}$, reflecting the economy’s productive capacity:
$$
r \approx g_{\text{real}}.
$$
Connecting nominal interest rates and nominal GDP growth
Substituting $r \approx g_{\text{real}}$ into the Fisher equation:
$$
i \approx g_{\text{real}} + \pi.
$$
Combining this with the equation for nominal GDP growth \eqref{eq1}:
$$
g_{\text{nominal}} = \pi + g_{\text{real}},
$$
we find:
$$
i \approx g_{\text{nominal}}.
$$
References
Blanchard, O. (2017). Macroeconomics (7th Edition). New York: Pearson.

everything clear, expect for why real interest rates tend to align with the growth rate of real GDP, can you please elaborate on this?    P.S. I'm taking a Bachelor in Economics, the  module concerned  is "Foundations of Macroeconomics".

The so called natural rate of interest is determined by the supply of loanable funds (aka degree of consumer savings) and the demand to borrow money.
